# Formal Obligation

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

Can you download the VERPFLICHTUNGSERKLARUNG  Formal Application; If so, please forward the link.

Answer (score 2):

The form is available from, among others, [Berlin (pdf)](https://www.berlin.de/formularverzeichnis/?formular=/labo/zentrale-einwohnerangelegenheiten/_assets/antrag_ve-25_5_18.pdf).  For more information, see their page [Verpflichtungserklärung für einen kurzen Aufenthalt](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/120691/) (in German).

Comment: Note that the form must be filed with the municipal authorities of the person who gives the bond. He or she will need to find the correct local office.